# Call to open on MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0 object fails

Tags: vbscript

Need to do a GET from VBScript to a web page to verify it is accessible.  This code used to work fine:

```
With CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
  .Open "GET", "https://www.google.com", False
  .Send
  content = .ResponseText
End With
```

Now, the code above fails with permission denied on the CreateObject line. Obviously a OS security configuration change.

I tried using MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0 object instead as suggested by other posts (see code snippet below):

```
With CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
  .Open "GET", "https://www.google.com", False
  .Send
  content = .ResponseText
End With
```

This code fails with the error message "the specified procedure could not be found" Code: 8007007F Source: msxml6.dll.

What on earth? It's implying a syntax error with the .Open.  The CreateObject call works fine so that gets it past the permission error, but it's saying the "Open" sub is not available for the MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0 object?

Other Info:

Windows 10 Enterprise
Build: 10.0.19042

Comment: Something has obviously changed on your machine, possibly related to permissions. Test under another user account to see if it's profile related.

Comment: I knew that for the first, but was looking for an alternative for the second.  "the specified procedure could not be found" is a terrible error message. It implies syntax.  The issue was actually with McAfee Endpoint Security.  In my humble opinion, the second message, should have also been a permission denied message

Answer (score 1):

Looks like McAfee Endpoint Security is causing this.  The runtime error dialog from wscript.exe made it seem as if there was a syntax error in the VBscript code, but I guess McAfee has intercepted the event and really confused wscript.exe. Here's the message I found in Event Viewer if it helps anyone.  I guess if I want this changed, I'll need to contact the McAfee Endpoint Security manager and have them put in an exception if they are willing.

> EventID=18060
>
> domain\user ran C:\Windows\System32\wscript.exe, which attempted to access >the process winhttp.dll, violating the rule "ASR : File Download attempt by >Scripts", and was blocked. For information about how to respond to this >event, see KB85494.